# What does the novalidate HTML attribute do?

Tags: html, forms, attributes

What does the `novalidate` attribute do in a form tag in HTML?

Comment: [`novalidate`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) attribute tells browser to not do the default (done by the browser itself) form validation. This attribute was introduced in HTML5.

Answer (score 43):

Adding a `novalidate` attribute to the form element prevents **native** validation on form elements (if applied), allowing your JavaScript unobstructed ability to manage all validation

[Based on the HTML5 course on Linda:](https://www.lynda.com/HTML-tutorials/Creating-Submit-buttons-bypass-validation-rules-using-novalidate-attribute/80852/84916-4.html)

> The novalidate attribute prevents forms from running their validation
>   logic when the form is submitted. In other words, it always lets the
>   form submission process go through regardless of what the results of
>   validation logic would normally.Now why would you want to do some like
>   that? Well, one main use of this is to allow a user to save a form's
>   state so they can continue later without having to first validate all
>   the entries.
>
> So if your web site, for example, is having a user fill out a form and
>   the user wants to be able to save their progress, you can disable your
>   form's validation laws, and let them submit the form and continue on
>   later without having to force them to validate everything first
>
> There are two attributes actually that enforces behavior. If you want
>   to use novalidate directly on the form tag, you can use the novalidate
>   atrribute right on the form itself.You can also do this on per control
>   basis.